# Increase the margin between y axis values of a Column chart

Tags: apache-flex, charts

here is the image of column chart which i am drawing by using the samples provided in flash's help page.

Now i need to increase the margin of y axis series. For example, as per the attached image it is 200 and i want to make 500 so that less points should come on y axis label bar.

[image]

Thanks in adv!

Comment: Use mx:LinearAxis maximum="5000" minimum="0"

Answer (score 0):

1. You can create your own labelFunction through which you can change the default values of Y axis labels.
2. You can also use the Mahesh Parate's suggestion to set the min and max values of the Y axis label.
3. OR you can use both 1& 2 together

Answer (score 0):

I dont think the above answers actually satisfies what was i looking for.

There is simple attribute in flash "interval". it does the trick.